# how to define function with generic in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am defined a function `api_post_con` like this in typescript:

```
export const RequestHandler = {
    api_post_con:(url: string,data: any) => {

    }
}
```

now I want the `api_post_con` function with generic like this function:

```
export function api_post<T>(url: string,data: any): Promise<T> {
    return fetch(url,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': 'xxxxx'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
        .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText)
        }
        return response.json() as Promise<T>
        })
}
```

how to change the `api_post_con` function just like `api_post` function that return generic type? I have tried like this but did not work:

```
export const RequestHandler = {
        api_post_con<T>:(url: string,data: any):Promise<T> => {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Generic function type parameters always immediately precede the opening parenthesis of the call signature, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpgK6N).  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to declare a class, not an object literal:

```js
export class RequestHandler {
    api_post_con<T>(url: string,data: any):Promise<T> {
        return {} as Promise<T>;
    }
}
```